# Create dummy column that indicates when something happened between an interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have two tables which consist of the following columns:

Table1:

`ID` 
`N` which describes an `ID` who did something, e.g. for the first time, then a second time, etc.
`START_DATE` is related to column `N`. It describes the date when an `ID` did something.
`STOP_DATE` 1 day before column `GROUPS` changes from 0 to 1.
`GROUPS` is a grouping variable.

Table2:

`ID`
`EVENT_HAPPENED` is a date on which an event happened.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/M45xEbZQ)

Table1:

| ID | N | START_DATE | STOP_DATE | GROUPS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-26 | 2023-04-13 | 0 |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-02-05 | 2023-04-13 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 2023-02-27 | 2023-04-13 | 0 |
| 1 | 4 | 2023-04-14 | 2023-09-13 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 | 2023-04-14 | 2023-09-13 | 1 |
| 1 | 6 | 2023-04-14 | 2023-09-13 | 1 |

Table2:

| ID | EVENT_HAPPENED |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-03-12 |
| 1 | 2023-03-18 |
| 1 | 2023-04-07 |
| 1 | 2023-05-31 |

So what I need to do is to check the minimum date of `EVENT_HAPPENED`. In this case, it is 2023-03-12 and then I reference it to table1 to create a column called `MARKER` which indicates with 1 that for all subsequent data entries for this ID, the event has already happened.
I also need to associate the smallest date on which the `EVENT_HAPPENED` occurred with the corresponding interval between `START_DATE` and `STOP_DATE` as a new column called `HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME` with the corresponding date as column `HAPPENED_ON`.

What I expect

| ID | N | START_DATE | STOP_DATE | GROUPS | MARKER | HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME | HAPPENED_ON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-26 | 2023-04-13 | 0 | 0 | 0 | *null* |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-02-05 | 2023-04-13 | 0 | 0 | 0 | *null* |
| 1 | 3 | 2023-02-27 | 2023-04-13 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2023-03-12 |
| 1 | 4 | 2023-04-14 | 2023-09-13 | 1 | 1 | 0 | *null* |
| 1 | 5 | 2023-04-14 | 2023-09-13 | 1 | 1 | 0 | *null* |
| 1 | 6 | 2023-04-14 | 2023-09-13 | 1 | 1 | 0 | *null* |

What I tried to do is the following:

```
WITH EventDates AS (
    SELECT
        ID,
        MIN(EVENT_HAPPENED) AS MIN_EVENT_DATE
    FROM
        Table2
    GROUP BY
        ID
),
IntervalDates AS (
    SELECT
        t1.ID,
        t1.N,
        t1.START_DATE,
        t1.STOP_DATE,
        t1.GROUPS,
        ed.MIN_EVENT_DATE AS HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME
    FROM
        Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN
        EventDates ed ON t1.ID = ed.ID
)
SELECT
    ID,
    N,
    START_DATE,
    STOP_DATE,
    GROUPS,
    CASE
        WHEN HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME <= START_DATE THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS MARKER,
    CASE
        WHEN HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME BETWEEN START_DATE AND STOP_DATE THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME,
    CASE
        WHEN HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME BETWEEN START_DATE AND STOP_DATE THEN HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME
        ELSE NULL
    END AS HAPPENED_ON
FROM
    IntervalDates;
```

The problem occurs here because the smallest `EVENT_HAPPENED` date is actually between `START_DATE` and `STOP_DATE` for the first 3 data entries. However, it happened **after** `START_DATE` 2023-02-27:

```
    CASE
        WHEN HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME BETWEEN START_DATE AND STOP_DATE THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME,
    CASE
        WHEN HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME BETWEEN START_DATE AND STOP_DATE THEN HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME
        ELSE NULL
    END AS HAPPENED_ON
```

which gives the following result:

| ID | N | START_DATE | STOP_DATE | GROUPS | MARKER | HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME | HAPPENED_ON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-26 | 2023-04-13 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2023-03-12 |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-02-05 | 2023-04-13 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2023-03-12 |
| 1 | 3 | 2023-02-27 | 2023-04-13 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2023-03-12 |
| 1 | 4 | 2023-04-14 | 2023-09-13 | 1 | 1 | 0 | *null* |
| 1 | 5 | 2023-04-14 | 2023-09-13 | 1 | 1 | 0 | *null* |
| 1 | 6 | 2023-04-14 | 2023-09-13 | 1 | 1 | 0 | *null* |

How can I adjust my code?

Thank you

------------------EDIT
When adding `ID`s who ever belong to `GROUPS` = 0 the `MARKER` column works fine, but the `HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME` indicator does not work nor the corresponding `HAPPENED_ON`.

Do I need to split `ID`s into those who belong to `GROUPS` = 1 and those who never do to run the RN?

Expected output:

| ID | N | START_DATE | STOP_DATE | GROUPS | MARKER | HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME | HAPPENED_ON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2023-01-26 | 2023-04-13 | 0 | 0 | 0 | *null* |
| 1 | 2 | 2023-02-05 | 2023-04-13 | 0 | 0 | 0 | *null* |
| 1 | 3 | 2023-02-27 | 2023-04-13 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2023-03-12 |
| 1 | 4 | 2023-04-14 | 2023-09-13 | 1 | 1 | 0 | *null* |
| 1 | 5 | 2023-04-14 | 2023-09-13 | 1 | 1 | 0 | *null* |
| 1 | 6 | 2023-04-14 | 2023-09-13 | 1 | 1 | 0 | *null* |
| 3 | 1 | 2023-01-26 | 2023-04-13 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 2023-01-31 |
| 3 | 2 | 2023-02-05 | 2023-04-13 | 0 | 1 | 0 | *null* |
| 3 | 3 | 2023-02-27 | 2023-04-13 | 0 | 1 | 0 | *null* |
| 3 | 4 | 2023-04-14 | 2023-04-13 | 0 | 1 | 0 | *null* |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have slightly updated your query to retrieve the correct *HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME*, I used the window function `row_number()` to pinpoint the nearest *START_DATE* relative to the event date :

```
WITH EventDates AS (
    SELECT
        ID,
        MIN(EVENT_HAPPENED) AS MIN_EVENT_DATE
    FROM
        Table2
    GROUP BY
        ID
),
IntervalDates AS (
    SELECT
        t1.ID,
        t1.N,
        t1.START_DATE,
        t1.STOP_DATE,
        t1.GROUPS,
        ed.MIN_EVENT_DATE AS HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY t1.N DESC) 
        - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID, t1.GROUPS ORDER BY t1.N DESC) AS grp
    FROM
        Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN
        EventDates ed ON t1.ID = ed.ID
),
closest_dates AS (
  SELECT ID, N, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, grp ORDER BY N DESC) AS RN
  FROM IntervalDates
  WHERE HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME BETWEEN START_DATE AND STOP_DATE
)
SELECT i.ID,
       i.N,
       i.START_DATE,
       i.STOP_DATE,
       i.GROUPS,
       CASE
          WHEN i.HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME <= i.START_DATE THEN 1
          ELSE 0
       END AS MARKER,
       CASE
         WHEN RN = 1 AND c.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END AS HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME,
       CASE
          WHEN RN = 1 AND c.ID IS NOT NULL THEN HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME
          ELSE NULL
       END AS HAPPENED_ON
FROM IntervalDates i
LEFT JOIN closest_dates c ON i.ID = c.ID and i.N = c.N
```

Results :

```
ID  N   START_DATE  STOP_DATE   GROUPS  MARKER  FIRST_TIME  HAPPENED_ON
1   1   2023-01-26  2023-04-13  0       0       0           null
1   2   2023-02-05  2023-04-13  0       0       0           null
1   3   2023-02-27  2023-04-13  0       0       1           2023-03-12
1   4   2023-04-14  2023-09-13  1       1       0           null
1   5   2023-04-14  2023-09-13  1       1       0           null
1   6   2023-04-14  2023-09-13  1       1       0           null
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/sEPc-79s)

---

Based on the recent simple data you provided in the comments, it appears that the question has transformed into a "gaps and islands" problem . This can be resolved using the difference between two row_numbers to identify the existing groups :

```
WITH EventDates AS (
    SELECT ID, MIN(EVENT_HAPPENED) AS MIN_EVENT_DATE
    FROM Table2
    GROUP BY ID
),
IntervalDates AS (
    SELECT t1.ID, t1.N, t1.START_DATE, t1.STOP_DATE, t1.GROUPS,
        ed.MIN_EVENT_DATE AS HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY t1.N DESC) 
        - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID, t1.GROUPS ORDER BY t1.N DESC) AS grp
    FROM Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN EventDates ed ON t1.ID = ed.ID
),
closest_dates AS (
  SELECT ID, N, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, grp ORDER BY N DESC) AS RN
  FROM IntervalDates
  WHERE HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME BETWEEN START_DATE AND STOP_DATE
)
SELECT i.ID, i.N, i.START_DATE, i.STOP_DATE, i.GROUPS,
       CASE
          WHEN i.HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME <= i.START_DATE THEN 1
          ELSE 0
       END AS MARKER,
       CASE
         WHEN RN = 1 AND c.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END AS HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME,
       CASE
          WHEN RN = 1 AND c.ID IS NOT NULL THEN HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME
          ELSE NULL
       END AS HAPPENED_ON
FROM IntervalDates i
LEFT JOIN closest_dates c ON i.ID = c.ID and i.N = c.N
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/MaMAhSja)

Comment: Thank you so much.
Now I included `ID` 3 who ever belongs to GROUPS = 0. But this interferes with the counting RN. https://dbfiddle.uk/pfLBrWoC
Do you have a solution for that? Maybe I have to split this into two CTEs? The `MARKER` column is correct, but `HAPPENED_FIRST_TIME` and `HAPPENED_ON` do not work.

Comment: Could you edit your question and include this scenario with the expected output ?

Comment: I added the expectation. Thanks.

Comment: Could you check my recent update ?

Comment: Perfect. Many thanks for your commitment.